# SHA-1 Collision Probability

Tags: probability, sha1, sha

I'm having difficulty working this out on paper and in my head. I know that is revolves around the Birthday Paradox, however, I cannot seem to comprehend the interchangeability of values between my question and BP's solution.

Alright, so I know that SHA-1 produces a hash of 160 bits.

> > Between two messages and the probability of 0.5, how many times should the said "attacker" have to search to find identical hash values?

I've come across a series of solutions from searching, but none that thoroughly walk me through the process and explain it in a way that makes sense to me. Below is the closest that I've been able to come up with during my search.

[image]

I hope this helps to explain my question.

Comment: I think that I solved it, to some extent. Basically since there is a total of 160 bits involved, 2^160/2, to find the number of searches to find the probability of 0.5.

If anyone has a better solution or can clarify on my solution, please do.

Comment: There is a Cryptography SE where such a question is suited...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right; this circles around the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). In hashing you are essentially trying to place a something that can be of theoretically infinite length into a fixed length string through a mathematical process; a collision is therefore inevitable.

The Birthday Problem basically means that suppose you had a hall full of people, you ask each person their date of birth. The probability of finding someone with the same birthday as another increases as you have more dates of birth which two people could have as the same. And eventually you will find someone who has the same birthday.

[image: Graph of the birthday problem]

Aaron Toponce wrote about this in his piece ["The Reality of SHA1"](https://pthree.org/2014/03/06/the-reality-of-sha1/) where he pointed out:

> SHA1 was meant to be a replacement for MD5. MD5 has an output space of
>   only 128-bits, where as SHA1 has an output space of 160-bits. SHA1 is
>   also designed differently than MD5, and is meant to not suffer the
>   same sort of weaknesses or attacks that MD5 faces. However, over time,
>   cryptographers have been able to severely attack SHA1, and as a
>   result, they've all been warning us to get off SHA1, and move to SHA2.
>   It should take 2^160 operations to find a collision with SHA1, however
>   using the Birthday Paradox, we can have a probability of 50% of
>   finding a SHA1 collision in about 2^80 operations. However,
>   cryptanalysists have torn down SHA1 to a complexity of only 2^61
>   operations. Even better.

Essentially, the SHA1 is a mathematical algorithm, weaknesses can be found in algorithms which make them easier crack and reduce the probability of a collision. This research, usually done by computer scientists, cryptographers and mathematicians then can be used to reduce the chance of finding a collision by using new algorithms to find new ways of finding collisions.